# What nation are the Orions part of?

Tags: star-trek

As of the TNG era onward, and in 'this universe' (by which I mean not in any alternate/parallel universes) are the Orion species part of the Federation, any of the empires or they an independent nation like the Ferengi?

Comment: They were neutral (e.g. not part of the Federation) circa 2269; https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr9Dc.png - ([Star Trek: Maps](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Maps))

Comment: *[Star Trek: Worlds of the Federation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Worlds_of_the_Federation)* lists Rigel VIII (e.g. Orion) and the other worlds of the Rigel system as being Federation worlds as of 2269; https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jBGF.png

Comment: In the Extended Universe (EU) books the Orions are generally referred to as being full members of the Federation as of 2369 - "*This, after a memorable meeting with Ambassador Hnada and other distraught representatives of the provisional Bajoran government, who had flown up to the station for the purpose of insisting that he do something to convince the Klystron and Orion ambassadors to change their minds about supporting Bajoran membership in the Federation.*" - [Betrayal](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Betrayal)

Comment: In the 2380s there are Orion serving in Starfleet. Though that doesn't necessarily mean they are Federation members.

Comment: @OrangeDog - There were also Borg and Ferengi in Starfleet

Comment: @Valorum exactly

Comment: Notably the Orion *species* doesn't just live on Orion, but lots of colony worlds.